# ClientContext + camlQuery.ViewXml

Tags: client-object-model, caml-query

I use SP Client and want to return ListItemCollection which will be filled with items from specific view which I choose. I get ViewQuery string by sending view index in viewcollection. Problem is in part where I send camlQuery to GetItems method
"ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);" because whatever camlquery is sent to GetItems I allways get ALL items from list instead of FILTERED ones, despite the fact that camlquery string are good and different every time.  Any suggestion?

```
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle(SPList);
        clientContext.Load(list);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        ViewCollection viewItems = list.Views;
        clientContext.Load(viewItems);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = list.Views[index].ViewQuery;

        ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(listItems);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this recently.

The Client OM version of CamlQuery behaves differently to how you think.

Inspect the results of list.Views[0].ViewQuery.

If it has a  tag around it, remove it before you assign to it CamlQuery.ViewXml. (possibly a bit tricky)

If it doesn't have a  tag around it, add one. (easy)

Then assign it to CamlQuery.ViewXml. Almost certain this will work, as the symptoms you describe are identical to what I had, except I was using the Silverlight object model. Same objects, however.

EDIT:

Also, streamline your code, you've got a lot of "blocking" operations there that you probably don't need...

```
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle(SPList);
ViewCollection viewItems = list.Views;
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = list.Views[index].ViewQuery;
ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.Load(list);
clientContext.Load(viewItems);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you man!! My ViewQuery looks like: 
<Where>
  <Gt>
    <FieldRef Name=\"acis_savjetovanje_datumpocetka\" />
    <Value Type=\"DateTime\">
      <Today />
    </Value>
  </Gt>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name=\"acis_savjetovanje_datumpocetka\" Ascending=\"FALSE\" />
</OrderBy>

If I understand you good I should add tags <view> and <Query> around this from ViewQuery. to create good ViewXML. Is that idea?

Comment: Yup, that's it. Just use string concatenation, so do something like "<View>" + camlQuery.ViewXml + "</View>"

Comment: Thanx again. That's it. You rock :)